# Riddle-Yet-Another-Riddle!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Let us tell you a story about nothing but us.
>   Unbleached  sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss!
>   We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a needless lane.
>   Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!
>
> One of us resides in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.
>   Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!
>   We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But it's just fine.
>   Okay, let us give you a little hint, the hint is our length, which  is fifteen minus nine!

**HINT**

> Sorry, no hints. You have already got all the hints up there :)

**ACTUAL HINT**

> Only one of the answer(with max votes) rightly revealed a good amount of things in the riddle. Went close but didn't hit the right answer and hence was unable to explain all the lines. Answer needs a little bit of scientific knowledge. Only line 3 has a little bit of word play.

Comment: "One of us reside in each line here.", does that mean, a single entity on all lines?, or multiple entities on multiple lines, one one each?

Comment: @demonofthemist- It's a riddle and hence is supposed to be confusing :) But for clarifications, the riddle speaks about itself. Hence..

Comment: is answer "riddle" ?

Comment: @AnmolMittal - Sorry. It's not.

Comment: That hint......

Comment: Am I able to add a second bounty ;)

Comment: A hint is really called for. There have been too many answers and none correct so far..

Comment: An actual hint please?

Comment: @Techidiot Are the random spaces at the end of each line deliberate?

Comment: @Sid- Incoming :)

Comment: @Oliver- No. Random spaces are not deliberate. Added a hint.

Comment: Thoughts turn to some kind of subatomic particle, maybe?

Comment: I have a riddle, I have another, uhh, another riddle! I have a riddle, I have a yet, uhh, yet riddle! Another riddle, yet riddle, uhh, riddle yet another riddle! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1W3sslyiUfg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> **Clones**.

We assume the answer is plural, as the riddle subject always speaks of itself in the plural ("we", "us"), so we're looking for a plural thing.

> Let us tell you a story about nothing but us.

> The riddle is speaking of its own solution (no surprise there).

> Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss!

> "Bleached" can mean "artificially produced; not natural", as in "bleached blonde";
>  **Clones** can be created naturally (identical twins) or artificially.

> We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a needless lane.

> The now-corrected ***ACTUAL HINT*** tells us this line (alone) has a little word play.
>
>  (I had a different answer here previously; see edit history if you care). The corrected hint says this is a word play thing, which OP was kind enough to explain in the Sphinx's Lair, as it was obscure.
>
>  Per OP, the intention was to read "had a needless lane" as indication that the "a" was needless, leaving "had lane"; and somehow we were to intuit that those words should be merged and commingled to give "Haldane", the person who invented the word **clone**.  Also, "type" was intended to clue "person", because one definition of "type" reads "a person or thing exemplifying the ideal or defining characteristics of something".  That's some leaps of logic that goes well beyond "word play" — but whatever, an answer is an answer. :)

> Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> **Clones** may be created by magic (plenty of fantasy stories feature spells that allow one to take on someone else's appearance, or to create a copy of a person outright).  We already have cloning of animals.  Some people believe cloning of people in the future is inevitable.  But clones wouldn't be created without a good reason ("in vain"); they'd be made for a specific purpose.

> One of us resides in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> One **clone** appears in each line of the riddle - that is, one duplicated word.

> Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!

> If you ask someone if those pants make you look fat, they may very well fib to avoid hurting your self confidence. But exact **clones** of you won't have that option. They're the same size, and you wouldn't even have to ask as you could see their size for yourself. (Making it pointless for a clone to lie about its size.)

> We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But it's just fine.

> **Clones** are supposed to look exactly like their original.  Think also of, say, the Clone Armies of Star Wars, which look unvaried indeed.

> Okay, let us give you a little hint, the hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> The length of the word **clones** is $15-9=6$.

> **TITLE**
>   Riddle-Yet-Another-Riddle

> Like the lines of the riddle, the title also has one cloned word, "riddle".
>  Possibly referenced in Line 5's "**Top** to the bottom".

> **HINT**
>   Sorry, no hints. You have already got all the hints up there :)

> ... itself contained another cloned word, "hints", so wasn't really a non-hint entirely.

> **ACTUAL HINT**
>   Only one of the answer(with max votes) rightly revealed a good amount of things in the riddle. Went close but didn't hit the right answer and hence was unable to explain all the lines. Answer needs a little bit of scientific knowledge. Only line <strike>2</strike> $3$ has a little bit of word play.

> The max vote answer's answer was **repeat**, suggesting that the only noteworthy feature found on every line of the riddle — the repetition of a word — was not only intentional but was key.  This got me thinking along the lines of "copies", which would explain most clues but definitely not all; from there to **clones** was a short drive, and let me explain pretty much everything.
>  The other items in the hint I've already used earlier.

Comment: @Rubio- Check my edit of hint. Line 3 has a litle wordplay. Also, if you can make a couple of more edits - Unbleached is a synonym for natural. Clones can be produced naturally or artificially. Magical is a metaphor.. Clones are an amusing display of science. . If you can find the word play in line 3 it will be great. :) But yes, this one is CORRECT!!!

Comment: (Haldane, not Hadlane.)

Comment: Done. Green tick :)

Comment: Nice!!! Hey, even though you hit the right answer, I gave the bounty to Tom, because I think he spotted the essence (repetition) first.

Comment: @Tinkidinki Wow. not cool. Tom was not the first to spot the repetition of words, just the first to post that as an answer despite it being applicable to *maybe* half the riddle (as his own answer both shows and admits) -- and it was posted well before you put up your bounty, which was ostensibly to go to someone for getting it right.  It's your bounty, do what you want with it, but that kinda stinks.

Answer (score 12):

I think you are

> repeat - a repetition of the same word on each line

On each line the relevant

> repetition is: us, sometimes, type, we, line, you, we, hint

Some lines which clue this - I don't think I have solved them all are:

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom.

> There is exactly one repetition on each line

We might look unvaried, we were meant to be.

> The repeated word is unvaried!

hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine

> repeat is six letters long

Comment: Nope. Good one but not the answer. Though +1 for the attempt

Comment: Wow I really thought this was it!

Comment: @Xenocacia- It does fit many lines. But doesn't fit all :) Else would have been the right one.

Comment: Still no answer? I hate you.

Comment: @jacksonecac That escalated quickly ...

Comment: I gave the bounty to you, because I think you spotted the essence first. Well done!

Comment: @Tinkidinki - thank you very much for this.. I was very intrigued by this puzzle but couldn't fit the clues - which the accepted answerer (well done!) managed to do. It was quite an ingenious one.

Comment: @Techidiot - I really enjoyed your puzzle and the hidden work that went into it. I think the system is making me wait until this one for the accepted ans to go through first before the one I wish to award for the question. Also appreciate Tinkidinki too.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the bounty - very stand-up of you, sir.  And props for the bounty to OP as well, but ...

Comment: @Techidiot I'm pretty sure you're going to have to post an answer of your own here to get the bounty.  Maybe one of those wrap-up posts, explaining how you put it together and what your intended solutions for each clue were.  Bounties can only be given to answers, not questions.

Answer (score 4):

Shot in the dark.

Are you

> Letter(s)?

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us,

> A story has nothing but letters

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> Letters are magical because they can create words and stories

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> At least one in every line

Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> Letter is six characters?

Comment: Nope. Nowhere close. Sorry. But good try. :) +1

Answer (score 3):

thank you for the riddle. May this be an anwser ?

> spaces ? or rhymes ?

**EDIT** 
OK, so I'm thinking to

> dictum

Reasons

> - because they can be rude or elegent (line 2)
>  - they're used to illustrate an idea (line 3)
>  - they can apply to several domains (line 4)
>  - they have rhymes and are often yoda spelled (I mean the sentence is built upside down) (line 5)
>  - they're affirmative (line 6)
>  - it's difficult to change one of them (line 7)
>  - the answer is 6 letter length (line 8)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange. Please take a tour and check how you can improve the quality of your answer. Explain why your answer suits. And, no, this is not the answer. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry. But again, incorrect answer. Oh and +1 for the attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is a

> Mirror

Expanded a bit from Tom's answer,

> There are words repeated on each line, this would be like a reflection in a mirror (typically this is interpreted by the reflection being backwards, but seeing someone in front of a mirror could be like seeing double).

I haven't solved each line yet, but a few thoughts:

```
Let us tell you a story about nothing but us,
Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss,
```

> googling mirror + bleach yields some results about making mirrors look more antique through a bleaching process?

```
We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a lane!
```

> Videos of mirror fabrication shows a conveyorbelt/assembly lane system. I feel that the word 'type' has some importance though, and I can't quite key in on it.

```
Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!
```

> Mirrors are often magical in stories, as well as a tool for the vain.

```
One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.
```

> Each line has a repetition in it, as if seeing a double.

```
Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!
```

> Mirrors reflect you, so it's a way to check/see your size.

```
We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine,
```

> While frames may differ, mirrors themselves are just the reflective surface?

```
Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!
```

> 15-9 = 6 - number of letters in mirror. (aside, fifteen - nine could = fft (removing the letters) if anyone can take that idea in a different direction).

Comment: Again, no! Also if it was mirror the words would have been mirrored like we->ew etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're a

> comma

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us,

Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss,

> Different font colors can brighten your commas

We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a lane!

> Originally denoted as a [dot between words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#History).  The "lane" would be top, middle, or bottom.

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> Commas are used in some date representations

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> There's a comma on every line

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!

> Different font sizes

We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine,

> Looks the same and is supposed to

Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> There are 15 comma-like characters (, and ') in the question.  I'm guessing the fact the numbers are written out has some significance, but I'll have to look into it later.

Comment: There is no comma in the first line. Sorry. No. And the last one is a too much of a stretch. :)

Comment: @Techidiot Ah, there was a comma at the end of the first line when I started this answer.

Comment: Oh, you might have started 2hrs back and posted 1.5 hrs later. Anyway, its not right. Though nice attempt but too much of stretch :)

Answer (score 2):

You're a

> period

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us,

Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss,

> Don't quite understand this one.

We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a lane!

> Periods were't really a thing until the printing press was invented. The printing press is the "lane"

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> Period also means a length of time

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> There's a period on every line

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!
We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine,

> Periods are generally the same size...just a dot.

Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> 15 - 9 = 6. Period is 6 letters

Comment: This sounds more like a lateral thinking. Sorry not right.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> pixels.

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us.

> The entire story (riddle) is displayed via pixels

Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss!

> If bleaching refers to shades, or white and black, pixels would fit this bill.

We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a lane.

> Pixels are arranged in a grid, and so have rows and columns, either one of which could be a lane. Furthermore, there are different types of pixel color representation. RGB, CMY(k),...

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> Modern monitors are a thing of engineering wonder. Dare I say magical? They'll also probably be used for the foreseeable future, and even when we get holograms, they'll still have many, many uses.

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> It's all displayed with pixels.

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!

> With monitors, a pixel is the base unit of measurement. In other words, the size of a pixel is indeed a pixel, forming a tautology, which can never be false.

We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine.

> Individual pixels are nothing if not uniform. But that's fine, even desirable, given their purpose.

Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> Pixels has six letters. 15-9=6.

Comment: Sorry. Its not. Too much of stretch with the size thing. Also, Unbleached is not related to shades :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this riddle talking about

> Vowels

Because

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us.

> riddle has high number of vowels

Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss!
We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a needless lane.
Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> haven't got any explanation yet(maybe :  'vowels and their places in words' is always a topic to discuss )

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> They are in every line.

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!
We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine.
Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> Length of vowels is 6(i.e. 6 letters)

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add in an explanation as to why you think it is correct? Thanks!

Comment: @Deusovi yes, I am working on it

Comment: @smriti- Sorry. But it's not the right answer. Also, I am not sure if you would be able to explain it either. But you can try and go for it.

Comment: @Techidiot yea, i figured, its a little bit of stretch

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> **return**

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us.

> this riddle refers to (carriage) returns

Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss!

> I assume the 'bleaching' refers to its visibility. Sometimes one can view this character in text editors, and it's often useful to refer to a return as `\r` or some other combination of other drawn characters.

We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a needless lane.

> You can type a return, and the needless lane might refer to the row on the keyboard on which the return key sits.

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> This line is bamboozling, but the *we shall never go in vain* might just refer to the usefulness of a key which produces a newline character?

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> This is the line on which pushed me to post this answer because I think that this is the most unambiguous hint of all the lines of the riddle. Each line (importantly, I think, the blank line) ended by a press of the return key.

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!

> Any character has a defined size depending on which encoding is used

We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine.

> returns don't look different from one another?

Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> the word *return* is six characters long

Also:

> I think the repeated characters in each line may have some significance. You can take a rearrangement of "us sometimes type we line you we hint" and get "hint: sometimes you type us (we line we)".

One more thing:

> not really related to this answer but I noticed that there's a strange number of spaces at the end of each line (3-2-8-3-1-4-4-4-4). Thought someone might run with this idea if I'm wrong.

Comment: Good one with a little stretch here and there. But not the answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> truths

Explanation:

> 1. Each line is about it
>  2. White lies?
>  3. ?
>  4. ?
>  5. "We can't deny."
>  6. "we won't lie!"
>  7. the truth will not vary
>  8. truths is 6 characters

Comment: Sorry. Its off the track and incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> A riddle

Unbleaches sometimes, sometimes not

> Some are easy, some are not

We were fabricated to some type, and that type had a lane

> No idea...

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> For those who cannot solve those, riddles may seem magical; lets hope that riddles will still be there in the future.

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> Each line is a riddle itself that has to be solved, to combine it with others to get the solution

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!
We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine,

> No idea again...

Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> Another six letter word...

I thought I would give it a shot :)

Comment: Well. Again, no where close. And you know that very well :) Also Unbleached does not mean Easy.

Comment: Yeah I guess... But longer bus tours tend to bring me to weird decision... And it could not harm. One option less for the person who will finally get it :)

Comment: @Techidiot Oh and with unbleached I thought of Some are made with more misleading information making them some kond of unbleached and some are not...

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> >

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us,

Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss,

> Sometimes they are hidden, other times they are visible -- that's up to us

We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a lane!

> They were typed on a keyboard, which has a row

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> Not sure on this one

One of us reside in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> Each line of your post contains a > to start

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!

> They will always say greater than

We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But its just fine,

> Not sure

Okay, let us give you a little hint, hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> Not sure

Comment: Many Not-Sure's :) But again, no. And yes, Unbleached doesn't mean hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are:

> stains

Reasons:

> - Sometimes stains are caused by bleach, sometimes not
>   - Stains do not go away without a lot of effort (....in vain....)
>   - Each line of the riddle contains the letters to make the singular form of the word (i.e., stain)
>   - Sometimes stains are created by accident, sometimes on purpose and evenly sized (unvaried)
>   - The word stains is six letters long

Comment: Sorry. A lot of stretch here. Off the track. Nice try.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Double

One of us resides in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.
Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!
We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But it's just fine.
Okay, let us give you a little hint, the hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> Each line contains some word twice. us, sometimes, type, we, line, you, we, hint. They don't want you to ask for their size because "double size" means greater quantity or Double type in programming is meant for large numbers. Also they look unvaried because doubles look the same. The word has six letters.

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us.
Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss!
We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a needless lane.
Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> After introduction, it refers to double data type and after that to body doubles / twins used in many magic tricks.

I'll update the post if I got it right.

Comment: Sorry. It's not correct. Programming part was a stretchhh....

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, just thought I'd take a shot.

Is it

> Carbon

One of us resides in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> I don't know, maybe Carbon is in the screen?

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!

> The size of a Carbon atom is very small.

We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But it's just fine.

> The structure of a Carbon atom is very definite.

Okay, let us give you a little hint, the hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> It is the sixth element, also it has six letters.

Comment: Sorry. Too much of stretch. No where close.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stretch but is the answer to the riddle

> answer

Each of the lines

> asks a question and responds with an answer, plainly states an answer or describes the word, answer.

Let us tell you a story about nothing but us.

> What is the story about? Answer us.

Unbleached sometimes, sometimes not, that's what they discuss!

> Unbleached refers to being **clean** = **clear**. 
>  People discuss questions and try to figure out the answers, clear or unclear.

We were fabricated by some type, and that type had a needless lane.

> Some create answers to questions that are unneeded.

Magical we might be, the future probably, we shall never go in vain!

> Questions might go unanswered thus the answer becoming magical.

One of us resides in each line here. Yes, every single line. Top to the bottom. We can't deny.

> Line answers question, "Where is the answer to the riddle?".

Don't you ask us our size. If you do, we won't lie!

> If you ask, it will respond with an answer.

We might look unvaried, we were meant to be. But it's just fine.

> Some answers to question seem similar.

Okay, let us give you a little hint, the hint is our length, which is fifteen minus nine!

> Finally, the question, "What is the length of the answer?" is answered with length = 6. Also answer is 6 letters in length.

Comment: Too much of stretch. Sorry. Incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Wrap-up:  The Making Of Riddle-Yet-Another-Riddle!

*This is not a solution to the puzzle, but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been [approved by the community](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

***Caution:** This post may contain spoilers.*

---

### Inspiration

I am still a learner and trying hard to make some good ones. Though having failed to meet the expectations with most of my other puzzles, this particular riddle was much liked, attempted by many and was considered worthy enough for a bounty and off-course criticized a little. :) So, it was nice to put a making behind this.

### Creation and Evolution

Riddle's, specifically with the rhymes, look simple enough for the ones who read it. Though I should say, a lot happens behind the scenes. They may include 8-10 lines, but to build those few lines is a big task when you don't want to give away everything and want to keep it fun. This first thing to do creating this one was to get an idea around which the riddle will be built. Being a fan of fictions, I chose the theme as "Clones".

Speaking of clones would have been quite a task and hence I chose to show them in the riddle. Again, showing it in the riddle would have attracted many answers like doubles, twins, repeat(which was one of them) etc. Hence, to add a little of uniqueness, I added a story to explain about the clones.

To make it even more unique, I added a hint stating the size in the riddle itself. Though, almost everything was already mentioned about the clones, I thought of adding a little bit of wordplay in and hence looked through Wikipedia if I can grab something useful. And hence I found "Haldane" who was the inventor of clones. To fit it in the riddle was a challenge because I didn't wanted it to spoil the riddle by making it easily visible and hence thought of splitting it into two parts and hence came up with HAD and LANE. Though, again, simply ending the line with had lane may not have been grammatically correct or if it was, it was too revealing. Reason being, when I googled "hadlane" it gave this ->

[image]

Hence, finalized it as *had a lane* and later *had a needless lane* to make it difficult.

Choice of the title was again an issue. But, I thought, I would keep the title related to the answer and hence went with *Riddle-Yet-Another-Riddle.* giving the idea.

### Resources

Not much was used except Google and Wikipedia. And a lot of PSE :)

### Takeaway

Every puzzle you create teaches you a lesson. So, following ones are mine -

1. There should not be any guessing required to solve a puzzle. Precise and correct information should be presented to help solver's lead to right direction.
2. When creating a riddle, do not use a direct synonym found through google. Instead understand the context and then choose the synonym wisely.
3. If adding something like wordplay, hint something which tells the solver's which part has wordplay.

I am glad to know that there were a lot many who attempted this one. Though not many went closer, I liked the Tom's answer who was the first to figure out most of the hidden things.

Thank you Rubio for explaining every line as expected, though some of them was a little ambiguous to explain.

Thank's to the community for serving a platform for letting us have fun!